# php mailheaders vs header on website email from

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am new to php and stackoverflow and I am trying to figure out a simple website contact form. I have the form and email functioning properly, but I have one nagging issue I can't figure out.

When the email is sent, the from email says myusername@p3pxxxxxx.com which is my server. When I direct the email to my domain based email account, they don't get to my inbox, I bet the spam filters are stopping the odd email address.  So I tried sending it to my gmail inbox, which worked, but I don't check that email regularly.  I'd rather have it go to my domain based email account.

So, I am looking for a way to edit the 'from' email address.  Instead of the user/server I would like it to use a real email address, mine or the person that sent it would be even better.  Here are a couple of attempts and what I currently have, none of which worked.

Couple of Attempts:

Attempted to pull the email address entered my sender.

```
//$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
//$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
```

This was another attempt.

```
//$mailheaders = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
```

What I currently have:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$security = $_POST['security'];

$to = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Message from Website";
$mailheaders = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
$message = "A visitor of exampledomain.com has submitted the following message.\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage: $message";


if ($security=="10") {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailheaders);
    header("Location:contact.php?s=1");
}
else {
    header("Location:contact.php?s=2");
}
?>
```

Followed the suggestion. Last attempt still didn't work...

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$security = $_POST['security'];

$to = "mail@example.com";
$subject = "Contact Message from Website";
$message = "A visitor of exampledomain.com has submitted the following message.\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage: $message";
$mailheaders = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: website@example.com";

if ($security=="10") {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailheaders);
    header("Location:contact.php?s=1");
}
else {
    header("Location:contact.php?s=2");
}
?>
```

Comment: the 2nd attempt should work but you have to switch `$mailheader` with `$message`, as the [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) points out!

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but my result didn't change.

Comment: I added the code to window above.

Comment: Code edited for correctness.  Does either example do what you want now?

Comment: Thanks for your comments I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alastair's correction should work.

When you were calling the `mail` function, you weren't passing in the variables in the proper order.

**How you were calling it:** `mail($to, $subject, $mailheaders, $message)`

**But the actual order is:** `mail($to, $subject, $message, $mailheaders)`

*Notice how I switch $message and $mailheaders*

It's a thing you can check on PHP's documentation, such as:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`